# Change Output Of API Request?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to use [Replicate](https://replicate.com/cjwbw/point-e/api) to send a text prompt and get a point cloud in return (to hopefully convert into a model) and bring into Unity. I got the request calling in Unity, but there seems to be two different output formats, "animation" and "json_file". Animation is a useless animated GIF, so I don't need it. I believe the JSON file contains the coordinates as well as the colour data (it may be a bit of a pain to stich a model together out of this, but one problem at a time), but I don't know how to access it.

I tried setting a header for `output` and `output_type` as `json_file` on both the second callback and the initial request, but it still just seems to return a single output, which is a rotating animated GIF of the model.

I read through [the docs](https://replicate.com/docs/reference/http), and can't really find anything on how to change the output. It does say "the response can be multiple outputs" but it's only ever returning one, even if I try waiting for a bit. The API on the Replicate website seems to show the `output_type` as `animation` but I'm not sure how I can change this. There's options on the website, but I need to change it directly through the API call.

Here's the script I'm using to call it,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Prompt
{
    public string prompt;
}

public class PostResponse
{

    public string completed_at;
    public string created_at;
    public string error;
    public string id;
    public Prompt input;
    public string logs;
    public string metrics;
    public Output[] output;
    public string started_at;
    public string status;
    public string version;

}

public class Output
{
    public string output;
}

public class ReplicateAPI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions";
    private string REPLICATE_API_TOKEN = "r8_DhOE6C7LuA7edPvLh7Io0ukwbmXCLEY450vc3";

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Predict());
    }

    IEnumerator Predict()
    {
        string requestData = "{\"version\": \"1a4da7adf0bc84cd786c1df41c02db3097d899f5c159f5fd5814a11117bdf02b\", \"input\": {\"prompt\": \"big funny colourful sofa\"}}}";

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(API_ENDPOINT, requestData);
        request.method = "POST";
        request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + REPLICATE_API_TOKEN);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("output", "json_file");

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error " + request.responseCode + ": " + request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
            PostResponse response = JsonUtility.FromJson<PostResponse>(request.downloadHandler.text);

            StartCoroutine(GetResult(response.id));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator GetResult(string id)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(API_ENDPOINT +"/" + id);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + REPLICATE_API_TOKEN);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("output", "json_file");

        PointEResponse pointEResponse = new PointEResponse();

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error " + request.responseCode + ": " + request.error);
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            pointEResponse = JsonUtility.FromJson<PointEResponse>(request.downloadHandler.text);
   
            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
        }

        if (pointEResponse.status != "succeeded" || pointEResponse.output.Length == 0) StartCoroutine(GetResult(id));
        else 
        {
            print("We got something!" + pointEResponse.output[0]);

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried contacting Replicate twice but never received any response.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should encode the `output_format` argument into the request data, since it is aligned with the `prompt` argument in your first link.

```
var prompt = "big funny colourful sofa";

string requestData = $@"{{
    ""version"": ""1a4da7adf0bc84cd786c1df41c02db3097d899f5c159f5fd5814a11117bdf02b"",
    ""input"": {{
        ""prompt"": ""{prompt}"",
        ""output_format"": ""json_file""
    }}
}}";
```

Comment: That's the solution, thank you very much! Seems to be considerably faster too, since it's not generating a useless gif anymore lol. Now the hard part, converting these points to a mesh, as well as generating a texture based on the output lol... One quick question, these backslashes throw me off lol, how would i add a "prompt" variable right after the \"prompt\"?

Comment: What did you mean add a "prompt" variable right after the \"prompt\"? It seems like you can provide only one prompt per request.

Comment: I mean, like {\"prompt\":  +prompt, prompt being a string that gets set elsewhere. The backslashes make the script confused as to where the quote ends, i'm not sure how to format it.

Comment: use string interpolation it's easier to read and more efficient than using `+` string concatenation ... e.g. `$" ...... \"prompt\": {yourPromptVariable} ..."`

Comment: You'd better use `JsonUtility.ToJson`. You can also use raw string literal with string interpolation (answer updated) if possible.

Comment: @shingo I think for string interpolation with raw string you would go e.g. `$$""" ... "input": { "prompt": {{yourPromptVariable}} ... """` ... oh you already updated ;)

Comment: @derHugo You need to keep the double quotation marks, C# won't add them for you.

Comment: @shingo ye good catch! Always forget JSON needs them ^^

Comment: Ah, i just realized you updated the comment with the correct formatting... but i'm getting a bunch of errors and i'm not sure why,
https://imgur.com/a/YBbQC2w

Comment: @Mashimaro7 I realized this is a unity question, c# 11 is not supported yet, so currently you can use verbatim string literals (begin with @) instead, but it requires using `""` and `{{` to represent `"` and `{` in strings. Using JsonUtility is still the best option.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, that worked! I tried making a custom class and converting it to JSON as the "requestData" variable but for some reason I was getting a 400 error. It's all good now, thanks for all the help.